# Strange libvirt/KVM issue, destroying instances?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, libvirt, kvm-virtualization

I have a libvirt/KVM server running on Ubuntu 9.04 with a variety of instances I use for testing. I was destroying instances via `virsh` and occassionally, destroying one instance would take out another. Is this normal? Because it's certainly not ideal.

```
virsh # list
 Id Name                 State
----------------------------------
 10 ubuntu904test        running
 14 centos5test          running
 24 ops1test             running

virsh # destroy ubuntu904test
Domain ubuntu904test destroyed

virsh # destroy centos5test
error: Failed to destroy domain centos5test
error: invalid domain pointer in no domain with matching id -1

virsh # list
 Id Name                 State
----------------------------------
 24 ops1test             running
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug. I suggest you fill out a bug report.

Comment: Sure enough, someone already did! https://bugs.launchpad.net/fedora/+source/libvirt/+bug/362288

Answer (score 1):

Having tried the KVM implementation in both Ubuntu and Fedora, I found the Ubuntu implementation hugely inferior to the Fedora one. I agree this might be a bug, but also, if you need KVM working right now: try the new Fedora 11.

Disclaimer: I do not dislike Ubuntu. I use both Fedora and Ubuntu at home. This is just what I experienced.

Comment: Ubuntu usually has lower quality in their packages from my expirience. That is not just true for KVM